# how to send variable values through url using javascript in google login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am sending question title value through js ,but I am not getting the value in my class.php file.Below is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bquestionname = $.trim($("#questionname").val());
  alert(bquestionname);
    $('#google_login').oauthpopup({
    path: rootUrl+'social/login.php?google&bquestionname='+bquestionname,
    width:650,
    height:350,
   });
});
```

Below is my class.php code:

```
if(isset($_GET['google'])){
$pArray = array();
$pArray['chat_question_title'] = isset($_GET['bquestionname']) ? $_GET['bquestionname'] : "";
print_r($pArray);
$res = $Social_obj->google();
}
```

Form the above code I am getting value in alert, but the value is not getting in my class.
I am getting url like this :

```
login.php?google&code=4/BoTIdK
```

Comment: you have to encode the url using some url encoding function and then transfer. encode and then pass through a GET method